# Combining Salesforce Triggers

Tags: apex, trigger

Are you able to combine 2 Salesforce Triggers together so that we only have one Apex Trigger per Salesforce Object. If yes, how?

**1st Trigger:**

```
trigger SL_Opportunity on Opportunity (before insert, before update, before delete, after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {
  SL_Trigger_Factory.createTriggerHandler(Opportunity.sObjectType);
}
```

**2nd Trigger:**

```
trigger OpportunityOwnerChangeTrigger on Opportunity (after update) {
    LoanTeamTriggerHandler.changeOwnerMethodOpportunity(Trigger.oldMap,Trigger.newMap);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that Salesforce recommends but I like having one trigger that handles before and one that handles after. 
Salesforce has very good documentation on this.

You can find an example of a trigger here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm

In your case it would look like this

```
trigger opportunityTrigger on Opportunity(before delete, before insert, before update, after delete, after insert, after update) {
if (Trigger.isBefore) {
     if (Trigger.isInsert) {
        SL_Trigger_Factory.createTriggerHandler(Opportunity.sObjectType);
     }
     if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
        SL_Trigger_Factory.createTriggerHandler(Opportunity.sObjectType);
     }
     if (Trigger.isDelete) {
        SL_Trigger_Factory.createTriggerHandler(Opportunity.sObjectType);
     }
} else {
    if (Trigger.isInsert) {
        SL_Trigger_Factory.createTriggerHandler(Opportunity.sObjectType);
     }
     if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
        SL_Trigger_Factory.createTriggerHandler(Opportunity.sObjectType);
        LoanTeamTriggerHandler.changeOwnerMethodOpportunity(Trigger.oldMap,Trigger.newMap);
     }
     if (Trigger.isDelete) {
        SL_Trigger_Factory.createTriggerHandler(Opportunity.sObjectType);
     }
     if (Trigger.UnDelete) {
        SL_Trigger_Factory.createTriggerHandler(Opportunity.sObjectType);
     }
}
```

However you might want to investigate if the code really needs to run on all.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have that trigger handler too!

You should have a class called SL_OpportunityTriggerHandler that extends SL_TriggerHandlerBase.

In the class, SL_OpportunityTriggerHandler you should do all your logic or at least point to a class to do your logic.

So simply move your change owner method into the handler and then drop it in the override for after update.

Now you can delete the OpportunityOwnerChangeTrigger trigger as it's redundant.